# clearInterval() issue using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues with the jQuery *clearInterval* function:

I'm setting my chat script to refresh the div every x seconds, but I'd like it to clear any previous chat intervals before it sets the new one up.

This is what I have and it doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        $('#chat_div').load('chat_grab.php');
    }, 5000);
});
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: How would you clear an interval that hasn't been created yet? You're essentially running `clearInterval(undefined)`

Comment: Ad now you're trying to clear the interval before setting it. The variable "interval" of this document is not any of the variable "interval" of any of the other documents.

Comment: Try putting the `clearInterval` within the body of the callback function.